# When and how to use as.name() vs.get() in data.table (ex. in looping over columns)?

Tags: r, data.table

My data.table `dt0` is :

```
ANSWER1 ANSWER2 ANSWER3 ANSWER4 ANSWER5 ANSCOUNT   SCORE100
 21      37      16      14      11     200784       61
 20      37      16      15      11     177165       60
```

`ANSWERx` are percentages. `SCORE100` is computed as  `SCORE100 := (100*ANSWER1*ANSCOUNT + 75*ANSWER2*ANSCOUNT + 50*ANSWER3*ANSCOUNT + 25*ANSWER4*ANSCOUNT) / (ANSWER1*ANSCOUNT + ANSWER2*ANSCOUNT + ANSWER3*ANSCOUNT +ANSWER4*ANSCOUNT + ANSWER5*ANSCOUNT)]`

In order to recompute `SCORE100` for all lines in my data-set, 
I need to automatically (in  a loop) multiply all `ANSWERx` by `ANSCOUNT`  in each row, then add all obtained multiplications and then divide by sum of all `ANSCOUNT`.

Can you help please,something along the lines below:

```
    for (c in paste0("ANSWER",1:5)) {
      dt0[, as.name(paste0(c,"_t")):= as.name(c)*"ANSCOUNT", , with=T]
    }
```

Thank you.

Here's the error. How to understand it and how to do it right?

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(dt0, , `:=`(as.name(paste0(c, "_t")), as.name(c) *  : 
 LHS of := must be a symbol, or an atomic vector (column names or positions).
```

Comment: A sub-question: What code will create automatically N new columns `ANSWER1_t`,...., `ANSWERN_t`, which are equal to `ANSWER1*ANSCOUNT`, ... `ANSWERN*ANSCOUNT` ?

Comment: I still want to know better how/when to use `as.name(x)` or `get(x)` with `data.table`, where x is passed as parameter (of a loop or function). Can you give me examples of good use of these, please? It would be great if 'data.table' help/manual would include these examples too...

Comment: `as.name` only fits if you are building an expression and applying `eval`, I think. Here you could do `for (c in paste0("ANSWER",1:5)) dt0[, paste0(c,"_t") := get(..c)*ANSCOUNT]` The dot-dot notation is fairly new, used to clarify that c refers to a variable "one level up" from the table

Answer (score 7):

To answer the overall question - "*When and how to use as.name() vs.get() in data.table?*".
In my experience, it is rarely needed when you can use existing R programming methods:

A functional approach similar to the other (now removed) answer:

```
dt0[, 
  newcol := Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, c(100,75,50,25,0), .SD)) / Reduce(`+`, .SD),
  .SDcols = ANSWER1:ANSWER5
]

#   ANSWER1 ANSWER2 ANSWER3 ANSWER4 ANSWER5 ANSCOUNT SCORE100   newcol
#1:      21      37      16      14      11   200784       61 60.85859
#2:      20      37      16      15      11   177165       60 60.10101
```

*Explanation:*

`Map` the weighting factor from `100-to-0` to the corresponding `ANSWER1:ANSWER5` columns, then `Reduce` them together using a `+` function. In other words, `100*ANSWER1 + 75*ANSWER2 + 50*ANSWER3 ...` etc.

Then use the same `Reduce` and `+` to form the denominator of the equation.

I think the multiplication by `ANSCOUNT` is pointless as it is in both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: A more convoluted way to use Reduce: `DT[, Reduce(\`+\`, Reduce(\`+\`, .SD[,-length(.SD), with=FALSE], accumulate=TRUE))/Reduce(\`+\`, .SD)*25, .SDcols=ANSWER1:ANSWER5]`

Answer (score 4):

This might not be able to compete speed wise with `data.table` but a base R option using `sweep` and `rowSums`

```
rowSums(sweep(dt0[,1:5],2, seq(100,0,-25), FUN = "*"))/rowSums(dt0[, 1:5])
#[1] 60.859 60.101
```

Or without using `sweep`

```
rowSums(t(t(dt0[,1:5]) * seq(100,0,-25)))/rowSums(dt0[, 1:5])
```

---

Both the approaches above implicitly converts the data.table to matrix and performs the calculation. We can have a slight improvement in the speed by using matrix multiplication and by avoiding the subset operation twice. (thanks to @nicola).

```
m <- as.matrix(dt0[,.SD,.SDcols=ANSWER1:ANSWER5])
m %*% seq(100,0,-25) /rowSums(m)
```

Comment: I imagine it will be very competitive actually. :-D

Comment: @thelatemail but it looses it's `data.table`iness I believe.

Comment: A small improvement in this direction might be the use of the matrix (`%*%`) multiplication: `m<-as.matrix(dt0[,.SD,.SDcols=ANSWER1:ANSWER5]);m %*% c(100,75,50,25,0) /rowSums(m)` (in your lines the coersion to matrix is implicit).

Answer (score 1):

I just found at [Assigning/Referencing a column name in data.table dynamically (in i, j and by)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818053/assigning-referencing-a-column-name-in-data-table-dynamically-in-i-j-and-by)
the inter-relationship between the two:

```
 eval(as.name(strFactor))
```

is the same

```
get(strFactor)
```

with only difference that former is "safer" than the latter (specifically, `get` doesnot work in some older versions ns some packages (e.g. in `data.table` older versions)

So,  with this caveat in mind, either of these two can be used - when looping through columns!