# Assigning/Referencing a column name in data.table dynamically (in i, j and by)

Tags: r, data.table

A) Instead of this (where `cars <- data.table(cars)`)

```
cars[ , .(`Totals:`=.N), by=speed]
```

I need this

```
strColumnName <- "Totals:"
cars [ , strColumnName = .N, by=speed]
```

How to do it?

B) Similarly (more general case) - instead of this:

```
cars[ dist > 50, .(`Totals:`=.N, x=dist*100), by=speed]
```

I need this:

```
strFactor <- "dist"
cars[ strFactor > 50, .(`Totals:`=.N, x=strFactor*100), by=speed]
```

This question is about GENERAL way of assigning/referencing column name variables in data.table, i.e. in 'j' (both RHS and LHS), as well as in 'i' and 'by' - dynamically. This is needed when are chosen elsewhere in  the code (e.g. a user my enter them in shiny app)

C) General case involving i,j and by - Instead of this:

```
 cars[ dist > 50, .(`Totals x Factor: ` = .N * dist), by=speed]
```

I need this:

```
strFactor <- "dist"; 
strNewVariable <- "Totals x Factor: "
strBy <- "speed"
cars[ strFactor > 50, .(strNewVariable = .N * strFactor), by=strBy]
```

Comment: The following does not work `col <- strColumnName ;
  cars[ ,  (col) = .N, by=speed]  ;
  cars[ , .((col) = .N), by=speed]  ;
  cars[ , .((col) = .N), by=speed, with=F]  ;
  cars[ , .(as.name(col) = .N), by=speed, with=F]`

Comment: `cars[ , .N, by=speed]` is an aggregation, not an assignment. Please clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve. For assignment, there are many dupes with similar title, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745169/dynamic-column-names-in-data-table

Comment: You need to use the `:=` set notation with this.

Comment: In my examples, instead of .N any other RHS statement can be used. And it is not about `:=`

Comment: Related: [Dynamically add column names to data.table when aggregating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239290/dynamically-add-column-names-to-data-table-when-aggregating)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**
Based on your clarifications, here is an approach with `setNames` and `get`. The trick here is that `..` instructs the evaluation to occur in the calling environment.

```
library(data.table)
cars <- data.table(cars)
strFactor <- "dist"
strNewVariable <- "Totals x Factor: "
strBy <- "speed"
cars[ get(strFactor)  > 50, 
     setNames(.(.N * get(..strFactor)),strNewVariable),
     by=strBy]
```

Comment: Yes - I've been thinking it has to be done with `get()` somehow ! Neat! -  I'm going to edit my question though - because in my coding practice, I'm trying "automate" (i.e. dynamically assign all variables) ALL parts inside the `data.table`, i.e. i, j and `by`

Comment: Awesome!  - This is what I'll be using from now on, with the only change that I will use `eval(as.name(strFactor))` instead of  `get(..strFactor)` - as suggested by @akrun, so that there's no need to memorize a new `..` symbol, when we can live without it.  Ian, perhaps, you can add this possible modification to your answer, and I will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: +1. The ```by``` argument does not need ```eval``` - this would work ```by = strBy```. Also, for people who prefer avoiding ```get```, you can use ```cars[[strFactor]] > 50``` and ```.SD[[strFactor]]``` for the i and j statements, respectively. A more robust API is in the works as well: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304

Answer (score 4):

We can use `:=` and wrap the variable with `()` to evaluate it instead of assinging it literally

```
library(data.table)
cars[ , (strColumnName) := .N, by=speed]
```

---

If we need a summarised column,

```
setnames(cars[, .N, by = speed], 'N',  strColumnName)[]
```

---

With the updated code

```
cars[eval(as.name(strFactor)) > 50, .(`Totals:`=.N, x=eval(as.name(strFactor))*100), by=speed]
```

Comment: So `eval(as.name(strFactor)) ` is the same as get(strFactor). Cool! Never knew. Thanks!

Comment: @IVIM yes, iit iis more safe compared to `get`